# Requesting Battery status from Mobile Bluetooth Printer (ESC/POS)

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I am successfully printing to a Bixolon SPP-R200 mobile bluetooth printer.

I would now like to ask the printer for it's current battery level. Based on the Bixolon command manual, the following command should accomplish this:

[image]

I am able to successfully send data to and read data from the printer (so that's not part of the issue as far as I can see). My problem is understanding the above given command:

1. Is there a special reason to write the value of fn and m directly into the format and later define the values of fn and m AGAIN ? In a previous command it was done differently: Instead of writing plain numbers into the Format, the variables were used and later defined in the range.
2. Am I correct in assuming a 4-byte long response from the printer?

My second issue is the ESC= n (Select peripheral device) command:

[image]

1. My printer has no display, it's a simple ESC/POS bluetooth printer. On the other end I have a smartphone (running Android, hence my code is in Java) that is sending these commands to the printer. Is the point of this command to send data to different interfaces within a printer (the display, the printing unit itself etc...)?
2. If my assumption at the end of question one is correct, then I suppose I'd have to pass n = 2, because the printer battery command specifically says: "**This command is effective, when the printer is disabled by ESC = n**"
3. How do I get "back to normal" after sending the battery command and evaluating the reponse, so I can continue printing to the printer? Would it be as simple as writing ESC = 1 (which would enable the printer again)?

Thanks in advance and please let me know if there are further questions.

Comment: if u got the answer,please update it here `thanks`

Comment: I will, however I've put that on hold for now, but if I ever do find it out, I'll post it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My printer has no display, it's a simple ESC/POS bluetooth printer. On
>   the other end I have a smartphone (running Android, hence my code is
>   in Java) that is sending these commands to the printer. Is the point
>   of this command to send data to different interfaces within a printer
>   (the display, the printing unit itself etc...)?

Point of this command is to identify which devices' battery status you are interested in. Your assumption is correct. So for your ESC/POS n=1 should be sufficient

> If my assumption at the end of question one is correct, then I suppose
>   I'd have to pass n = 2, because the printer battery command
>   specifically says: "This command is effective, when the printer is
>   disabled by ESC = n"

The instruction does not make sense. I believe the ESC points to the peripheral from which we need data.

> How do I get "back to normal" after sending the battery command and
>   evaluating the response, so I can continue printing to the printer?
>   Would it be as simple as writing ESC = 1 (which would enable the
>   printer again)?

This is a information related command and to my understanding it should not disturb the printer functionality. On receiving battery status , you can carry out the normal printing activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying, I'll check this out and accept your answer if I can get it to work like this :) otherwise I'll update my question with more details.